# Why is the verb "haben" placed before the subject in the first clause and in the second is not?

Tags: verb, word-order

> Jetzt haben wir hier keinen Computer, aber wir hatten ein letztes Jahr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

German does not have subject-verb-object order like English. It has [V2 word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order). All of the following sentences are correct:

> Jetzt haben wir hier keinen Computer, aber letztes Jahr hatten wir einen.
>   Wir haben jetzt hier keinen Computer, aber letztes Jahr hatten wir einen.
>   Wir haben jetzt hier keinen Computer, aber wir hatten letztes Jahr einen.
>   Jetzt haben wir hier keinen Computer, aber wir hatten letztes Jahr einen.

Note that the pronoun *ein-* needs *-en* in the accusative.

Comment: I've thought German can have also subject-verb-object order, but they mean different things ("Jetzt haben wir hier keinen Computer" has the focus on "jetzt", while "Wir haben hier jetzt keinen Computer" has not).

Comment: @peterh Jetzt weißt du das auch, aber letztes Jahr wusstest du das noch nicht ;)